# VHDL To verilog translation query

Tags: vhdl, verilog

I am trying to convert highly parametrized VHDL code to verilog. This VHDL code uses good amount of packages and records and I couldn't find the substitute for those in verilog. Also I am just 3 days old in verilog.

Package and entity files in VHDL are as follows:

```
package control_package is

type control_ca_out is record
   reset           : std_logic;
   end record;

type control_in is record
  clk             : std_logic;
  ha              : psl_control_in;
  dc              : dma_dc_out;
end record;

type control_out is record
  ca              : control_ca_out;
  ah              : psl_control_out;
  cd              : dma_cd_in;
end record;



entity control is
port (
   i                           : in  control_in;
   o                           : out control_out
);
end entity control;
```

Package and entity are in separate files. 
How do i implement the same in verilog? I know there's a way of packing all fields of records in single vector and then use part-select to access different fields of record. How could I include them in separate module in verilog?

Comment: You should seriously consider using SystemVerlog as this would be quite trivial to convert to a `struct` And SystemVerilog has packages. There is no such construct in Verilog.

Comment: I think i would switch to SV.

Answer (score 2):

You should seriously consider using SystemVerlog as this would be quite trivial to convert to a `struct` And SystemVerilog has packages. There is no such construct in Verilog.